# Reference overloading in module cnr

Tags: nodes

I am having two content-types:
1. article
2. Collection
Where multiple `articles` can be grouped in a `collection` i.e. `collection = n x articles`. Now problem is that when i edit collection and add an article to it which is already in another collection i get an error saying:

> Reference overloading: Collection 2 would of had 2 references and only 1
>   reference is permitted. Before adding a reference, you would need to edit
>   Collection 2 to remove an existing reference and resave this node to have
>   make it correspond. Or you could allow this reference instance to have 
>   more references,go to the cck field settings of the instance.

But I want is that previous reference should be removed instead of showing such an error.

Also I want that if i remove article by editing `collection` then it should refer an default collection.

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: What's a 'cnr'? The only reference on Google is for "Canadian National Railways", which I assume isn't what you were going for...

Comment: I think it's corresponding node reference

Comment: Yes, its corresponding node reference module. More can be seen via link: http://drupal.org/project/cnr